# replace values along a given axis

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following givens:

- a numpy hypercube e.g. `x = np.random.rand(8, 8, 8, 8)`
- a dimension index e.g. `dim = 1`
- a replacement array e.g. `y = np.random.rand(8)`

how can I replace all the values of the given dimension?

i.e., can i do better than:

```
if dim == 0:
    x[0,:,:,:] = y
elif dim == 1:
    x[:,0,:,:] = y
elif dim == 2:
    x[:,:,0,:] = y
elif dim == 3:
    x[:,:,:,0] = y
else:
    throw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index tuple via generator expression:

```
x[tuple(0 if i == dim else slice(None) for i in range(4))] = y
```

A more verbose version:

```
index = [slice(None)] * len(x.shape)
index[dim] = 0
x[tuple(index)] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the dim'th axis to the front:

```
np.moveaxis(x, dim, 0)[0] = y
```